# Can't create IndexedDB database in IE10

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, indexeddb

I write codes to create database:

```
var db;
var request = indexedDB.open("TestDatabase");
request.onerror = function(evt) {
  console.log("Database error code: " + evt.target.errorCode);
};
request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
  db = request.result;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(db));
};
```

It runs fine in FF/Chrome, the code: JSON.stringify(db) returns json object.
But, it doesn't work in IE10. The code: JSON.stringify(db) returns an empty object.

Do everybody have the same problem? Could you spent your time to help me please? Thanks.

Update: I also checked IndexedDB supported in IE10, like it:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
```

It returns true! I don't know JSON.stringify(db) always returns an empty object. :(

Comment: What if you log out request? See anything interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your indexed DB is acctually defined, that is also why you got a true from

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB
```

The issue is caused by the JSON.stringify(), it looks for a toJSON() method on any object it is asked to serialize. The variable db doesn't have it, and db.toString() is called.

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
var db;
var request = window.indexedDB.open("TestDatabase",1);
request.onerror = function(evt) {
  console.log("Database error code: " + evt.target.errorCode);
};
request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
  db = request.result;
  // extend the toJSON property for your indexeddb object
  db.toJSON = function() {
     return JSON.stringify({name : db.name});
  };
  //output: [object IDBDatabase]{constructor: IDBDatabase {...}, name: "TestDatabase", objectStoreNames: DOMStringList {...}, onabort: null, onerror: null, version: 1}
  console.log(db);
  // name is a inherit property 
  console.log(db.hasOwnProperty(name));
  // name is not a numerable property
  console.log(db.propertyIsEnumerable(name));
  // toString returns a native object, not a JSON String, thats why you have {} with JSON.stringify(db)
  console.log(db.toString);
  // JSON.stringify call the db.toJSON(), and get the "{\"name\":\"TestDatabase\"}"
  console.log(JSON.stringify(db));
};
```